# select top 10 items per city in SparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have the following table SQL table (SparkSQL) .

```
user_id, city, timestamp, item_id
```

I need to find the top 10 items of the given city (in terms of the number of time the item_id appeared in that city) in each given date.

I then did the following:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     ( 
                SELECT *, 
                       row_number() OVER partition BY city AS rn 
                FROM   mytable) AS foo 
ORDER BY rn DESC
```

However, though it sort by rn, it didn't just give me the top 10 elements of a given date. What would be a proper way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `of the given city ` and  `in each given date` means you must partition by city, date (could 1 date  have more than 1 timestamp?). `Top 10` means that you must `order by` **something** to get 10 top item. What is **something** you want to order by?

Comment: Assume it is the transaction records, item_1 could appear 1000 times, item_2 could appear 950 times ... in a given city. I want it is ordered by the number of times each item appears for that city. I.e. for each date, I want to show the top 10 best selling items for each city.

Answer (score 2):

Dont know what is the function to TRUNC time from timestamp in spark.

But first you need calculate the count, and then the row_number

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT   city, item_id, theDATE, cnt,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city, theDATE
                                    ORDER BY cnt) rn             
        FROM     (SELECT city,
                         timestamp,
                         item_id,
                         to_date(timestamp) as theDATE, -- remove time and leave just date.
                         COUNT(item_id) OVER (PARTITION BY city,  to_date(timestamp)) cnt
                  FROM   mytable
                 ) AS foo 
     ) AS boo
WHERE rn <= 10
ORDER BY city, theDATE, rn
```

Comment: the function to truncate time is to_date(...)